# Declaration of @class equivalent for a struct

Tags: objective-c

I would like to avoid importing `AVFoundation` framework in my header but I need to declare `CMTime`.

For `NSObject` I can do `@class AVPlayer;` and import everything in the .m file. How to do this with a struct like `CMTime`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to reference `CMTime` struct in the header, you need to include `<CMTime.h>`: forward-declaring a `struct` lets you use the name of the type in declarations of pointers, but not in declarations of members of that struct type.

In other words, you can do this:

```
struct CMTime; // Forward declaration of the struct

@interface MyInterface : NSObject
-(void)fillCmTime:(CMTime*)buffer;
@end
```

but you cannot do this:

```
struct CMTime; // Forward declaration of the struct
@interface MyInterface : NSObject {
    // This is not allowed
    CMTime time;
}
// This is not allowed either
-(CMTime)getTime;
@end
```

The reason that you can do `@class AVPlayer` and then use it in declarations of members is that Objective-C classes (`id`-types) are implemented as pointers. In fact, you cannot declare variables of an `id`-type without an asterisk.